# Do we really need degree constraints for ILP formulations of TSP problems

Tags: linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, traveling-salesman-problem

The Dantzig-Fulkerson ILP-formulation of the symmetric TSP is
$$\min\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^n c_{ij}x_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace}\quad\text{s.t.}\\ \sum\limits_{j\ne i,\,j=1}^n x_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace}=2\quad i=1,\,\dots,\, n;\\ 
 \sum\limits_{i\in Q}\sum\limits_{j\ne i,\,j\in Q}x_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace}\le|Q|-1\quad \forall Q\subsetneq \lbrace1,\,\dots,\,n\rbrace,\ |Q|\ge 2\\ x_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace}\in\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$$

> **Questions:**
>
> - is it known that the $n$ degree-constraints for vertices  be replaced with the single cardinality constraint
>   $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n x_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace}=n$$ because the maximal number of edges that a cycle-free graph with $n$ vertices can contain is $n-1$?
> - what are the tradeoffs for the reduced number of constraints?

Answer (score 3):

Don’t forget Johnson!

Although your proposed formulation is still valid, aggregating constraints yields a weaker linear programming relaxation.  You can find fractional solutions that satisfy the aggregated (cardinality) constraint but violate at least one of the degree constraints.  The net effect will typically be a larger search tree and a longer run time.

Comment: so being able to drop the degree constraints is only of negligible theoretical interest...